# how to "accurately" emulate a print-rendered output on an actual web page itself?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that has been styled to resemble what one would see in the print preview. Specifically, I'm attempting to **exactly** match where each line and page would break in the emulation with what is observed on the print preview.
In essence, I'm trying to simulate the correctness that Google Docs has, specifically an A4 with a portrait orientation.

Towards this effort, I'm maintaining two separate stylesheets – one for print and one for the `screen` media.

The approach I've taken is to maintain the same ratio of measurements between the two media. For example, the "page" element in the screen media has the dimensions of 2100px x 2970px ( which is proportional to an A4 portrait of 210mm x 297mm ).
I'm using pixel units in the screen stylesheet and mm units in the print stylesheet for everything – font-sizes, margins and paddings. This is because for print media, 1mm corresponds to 1mm physically ( as implied by this [article](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) ).
By default, the emulated print preview is extremely large. So, I have to zoom out or give a scale factor to the "page" element in CSS.
Depending on the browser, the zoom level in the browser and scale factor in CSS, text wraps and page break at different points.

At 33% zoom level on Chrome, I managed to match the line breaks between the two media exactly, but the page breaks were off by one line. There is an additional bit of margin that is implicitly being added at the bottom despite me explicitly specifying equal top and bottom margins in the `@page` rule. I confirmed this by physically measuring this using [ CMD SHIFT 4 ] on a Mac and measuring the difference between the two margins.

How do I pull this off?

I feel like I've missed something obvious or that they may be a way to trigger the print rendering engine instead of screen renderer.